# How to let all attributes which start with "ng-" inject language javascript in IntelliJ-IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ-Idea to edit html files. There is a useful feature called "Language Injection" in IDEA, I can easily configure some kinds of attributes (e.g. ng-model/ng-controller) to inject with javascript, but I don't know how to configure all the attributes which start with `ng-`?

[image]

Look at the image above, there is an important "Places Pattern", how to configure it?

Comment: Replace `equalsTo` with `startsWith("ng-")`?

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't work. I don't know why it doesn't work, although the syntax looks correct.

Comment: `+ xmlAttribute().withLocalName(string().startsWith("ng-"))` works for me.

Comment: I previous code has `.withParent` part, which make it not work. Please turn your comment to an answer, I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
+ xmlAttribute().withLocalName(string().startsWith("ng-"))
```

as the **Places Pattern**.